# ¿Cómo seleccionar registros mysql existan o no en la tabla foranea?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada claves y otra que es historial de claves

```
-claves
    id
    nombre
    clave

-historial_claves
    id
    clave_id
    fecha
```

Entonces cada vez que abro una pagina esta me guarda un registro  en mi tabla 2 (historial_claves) con mi clave y fecha. mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo consultar los ultimos registros insertados en tabla 2 del dia actual que tengan o no existencia en la tabla 2.

Ejemplo:

```
Claves
1, C1, 76895
2, C2, 45678
3, C3, 23452

historial_claves
1, 1, '2020-05-01'
1, 2, '2020-05-01'
3, 1, '2020-06-01'
4, 3, '2020-06-01'
```

Como se puede observar puede que un usuario con una clave especifica habra o no la pagina en un día, así que el registro no sera guardado, pero me interesa obtener sus datos aunque no haya accesado.

Ejemplo: si selecciono los registros de hoy ('2020-05-01'), que arrojara todos, incluso si hoy no tuvo registro la clave 3 (C3)

```
1,1,'C1','2020-05-01'
2,2,'C2','2020-05-01'
3,3,'C3', NULL
```

Intenté hacerla con:

```
    select *, max(fecha) as fdate from historial_claves group by clave_id;
    //esta si me arroja las últimas, pero solo las que tuvieron acceso

    select t1.*, t2.fecha as fdate from historial_claves t1 (LEFT/RIGHT) JOIN claves t2 on t1.clave_id=t2.id where t1.fecha = CURRENT_DATE group by clave_id
    //esta igual solo me da los que tienen registros
```

Alguna solución, gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu consulta la debes hacer de otra manera, considerando subqueries para poder obtener la información que requieres, para ello puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente.

```
SELECT *, max(fecha) AS fdate FROM historial_claves GROUP BY clave_id;
```

> Esta si me arroja las últimas, pero solo las que tuvieron acceso

Tomando como base esa consulta ahora solo los falta obtener todos los datos de los usuarios de forma indiscriminada

```
SELECT id,nombre FROM claves;
```

Una vez que tenemos eso debemos unirlos, ahi es donde entran las subqueries.

```
SELECT FROM A.id AS id, A.nombre as Nombre,IFNULL(B.fecha,"Sin ingreso") AS estado 
FROM (
         SELECT id,nombre FROM claves
     ) A
     LEFT JOIN
     ( 
        SELECT clave_id AS id, max(fecha) AS fecha FROM historial_claves GROUP BY clave_id;
     ) B
     ON A.id = B.id;
```

Y con eso deberias obtener una tabla con los datos mas o menos de la siguiente manera

```
id    Nombre    estado
1     C1        2020-05-01
2     C2        2020-05-01
3     C3        Sin ingreso
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo!!, es justo lo que buscaba!